# Why am I getting a 404 error when I go to localhost:8080/ using SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

So I've set up a first time test application Using Spring-Boot, Kotlin, and Intellij.

When I run the project everything seems to start up fine in the console.  But when I navigate to `http://localhost:8080/` in my browser  it gives me a 404 error and a page that looks like this:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this 
as a fallback.

Wed Aug 29 07:54:39 MDT 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

Why is it not navigating to the page I created?

Main Class:

```
package com.daniel.anderson.demo
import ... 


@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication

    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
    }
```

The Controller code:

```
package com.daniel.anderson.demo.controlers
import ... 

@Controller
class HtmlController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    fun blog(model: Model) : String {
        model.addAttribute("title","Blog")
        return "blog"
    }    
}
```

Mustach Files:
blog.mustache

```
{{> header}}

<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<p>hello world</p>

{{> footer}}
```

footer.mustache

```
</body>
</html>
```

header.mustache

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
```

Btw, I get the same error in postman.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the `@Controller` in my controller  If I changed the annotation to `@RestController`  then it worked.  My understanding is that I should be able to use the `@Controller` annotation but it appears you need the `@RestController`

So I found some really use full info here [Spring boot error 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38516937/spring-boot-error-404?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is the lack of the annotation @ResponseBody on the method

```
@GetMapping("/")
@ResponseBody
fun demo(model: Model): String {
    model["title"] = "Demo"
    return "Hello world?!"
}
```

This must work

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread and there is also an answer from the creator himself, but this behavior is typical if you have not added the mustache dependency.

```
<dependency>          
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I'm not 100% sure but if you change the annotation from @Controller to @RestController, the method returns only the string "blog".