# When redirect page to another page gives 404 error in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

After redirecting url is http://localhost:8080/signup, but there is **Whitelabel Error Page** with this message

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Wed Jan 11 22:20:52 PST 2017
>   There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>   No message available

```
@Controller
public class SignUp {
    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String goMainPage(){
        return "redirect:/signup";
    }   
}
```

Comment: Do you have a controller that can actually handle a request to the `/signup` endpoint?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/39017839/3368391

Comment: @AliDehghani no my controller like I posted above

Comment: @Boldbayar this problem occurs when i write "redirect:/signup".If I write just "signup",there is no error like this

Comment: Any request to `/` will be redirected to the `/signup` endpoint. You should define another method controller that can handle requests to that `/signup` url.

Comment: @AliDehghani thank you very much.It worked

Comment: haha thank you @AliDehghani