# org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorAttributes in SpringBoot 2.0.0.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I've recently moved the project to `SpringBoot 2.0.0.RELEASE` but I got a compilation problem

```
The import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorAttributes cannot be 
 resolved
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The interface `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorAttributes` was moved to 
`org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.error.ErrorAttributes` and 
`org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.error.ErrorAttributes` for reactive stack

Comment: Could you please provide more details on this move? I am asking because the following snippet would not build due to modified method signature: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31838439/2597758