# This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback. Why isn't HomeController passing the request to the view?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm following the example in Spring in Action 4th edition, Chapter 5 and running the Spittr example app.

When making any request, but for this question specifically:

http://localhost:8080/

I get the following error:

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   Error resolving template "home", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers.

I've looked at: [This application has no explicit mapping for /error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134333/this-application-has-no-explicit-mapping-for-error/40995336) where the solution was to have the main class at the top of the package hierachy. I've tried this without any success.

Here's the code:

**SpittrApplication.java**

```
package spittr;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpittrApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpittrApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**HomeController.java**

```
package spittr.web.controller;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

  @RequestMapping(method = GET)
  public String home(Model model) {
    return "home";
  }

}
```

The template is under src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp

The console logs the following error:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "home", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root cause

Comment: The error message talks about Thymeleaf. But you apparently want to use JSPs (although they're discouraged). Have you read https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-template-engines? Have youread https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-jsp-limitations?

Comment: @JB Nizet yes you're right, I blindly copied the book's code without noticing I was mixing JSPs with Thymeleaf view resolvers. Thanks.

Comment: You may not be handling a mapping for `/` when the app executes. Maybe you are missing the HomeController with a mapping for     @GetMapping("/")
    public String welcome() {
        return "<html><body>"
                + "<h1>Welcome to Spring & MongoDB & REST</h1>"
                + "</body></html>";
    }`. Make sure you have the structure mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39017839/2414129