# After Integrating Angular Project into Spring Boot Tomcat Server, Routing is not working

Tags: angular, spring-boot

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ListUserComponent } from './components/list-user/list-user.component';
import { UserFormComponent } from './components/user-form/user-form.component';
import { UserService } from './shared_service/user.service';
import { ListBioLogUserComponent } from './components/list-bio-log-user/list-bio-log-user.component';

const appRoutes:Routes=[
  {path:'', component:ListUserComponent},
  {path:'op', component:UserFormComponent},
  {path:'biologusers', component:ListBioLogUserComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ListUserComponent,
    UserFormComponent,
    ListBioLogUserComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [UserService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Paths `op`, `biologusers` are not working. But *Angular CLI* is working properly.

I just run `ng build --prod` and get all files from `dist` folder and put it into Spring boot project `resources/static` folder.

Comment: Does Spring resolve every route to index.html?

Comment: What is that error you are getting?

Comment: I am getting below error --  Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon May 21 19:25:53 IST 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: Have you checked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134333/this-application-has-no-explicit-mapping-for-error

Comment: This is not helpful

Comment: Hi now it is working as expected. The fix is imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      {useHash: true} // have to add this line
    )
  ],

Comment: Hi @JagadeeshwaranKuppuraj, Can you please post your answer here if it is working when type url and returns the url page. I mean that not redirect or forward home page  if the solution is.

Answer (score 0):

Put the entries in your `controller` also

Example:

```
@Component
@Controller
public class Ctrl  {

@RequestMapping("/ex1")
String Ex1(ModelMap modal) {
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping("/ex2")
String Ex2(ModelMap modal) {
    return "index";
}
```

}