# Tomcat Run but browser don't display localhost page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Welcome, I have problem with Spring Boot, I want start with Spring Boot and generate projekt using SPRING INITIALIZR. But when I want run empty projekt ( I don't change nothing after generate) my http://localhost:8080/ display me:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this 
as a fallback.

Wed Oct 10 22:45:26 CEST 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available
```

but server tomcat run coretly and looks good. Only these logs disturb me:

2018-10-10 22:47:35.378  INFO 2820 --- [           main] 
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)

2018-10-10 22:47:35.382  INFO 2820 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)

Thank you for any suggestions

Comment: Please read this link: [This application has no explicit mapping for /error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134333/this-application-has-no-explicit-mapping-for-error).  I believe one or more of the responses will help you.  If you resolve the problem, please post back how you did it.  If you're still having problems, please show us your main class (with the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation).

Comment: Can you add your project structure? It seems that you don’t have any page and controller in your project

Comment: PS: The errors you're showing are saying ... that Spring Boot is having problems displaying an error.  The root cause is that you haven't configured a "Controller" such that Spring Boot can find it.  Again: look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134333/this-application-has-no-explicit-mapping-for-error)