# Rest template application fails

Tags: spring-boot, resttemplate

I have written a simple code for springboot with rest controller. It runs fine but does not hit the endpoint.

**My Application class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootRestTemplateDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootRestTemplateDemo.class, args);
        System.out.println("Springboot Rest template demo");
    }

}
```

**My controller class:**

```
@RestController
public class ProductController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/product/details", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getProduct() {
        return "Product details";

    }
}
```

I expect a simple message using get request but it is not hitting the endpoint.
Input:
http://localhost:8080/product/details

output:

> Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for
>   /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
>
> Thu Mar 28 19:34:44 IST 2019 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available

Answer (score 0):

We would likely need to see the folder structure to fully understand. My current guess is its possible that your main class is not in a root package above other classes.

When you run a Spring Boot Application, (i.e. a class annotated with @SpringBootApplication), Spring will only scan the classes below your main class package.

see previous answer: [This application has no explicit mapping for /error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134333/this-application-has-no-explicit-mapping-for-error)

Comment: Thanks Shane, It was indeed the folder structure issue as you mentioned above. I changed it and works fine now.