# Browser does not see the proper mapping

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller, mapping, microservices

I wanted to create simple **microservice application** using 3 **spring-boot applications**. I have started setting the request mapping to the `@RestController`, but my application does not see proper mapping. I mean when I try to connect to **localhost:8080/catalog/something** (I have stared Tomcat Server on my own computer 8080 port, as you see), my browser sending a error, like this.

> ```
> Whitelabel Error Page
> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
> Tue Jun 16 13:04:34 SAMT 2020
> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
> ```

As I know, it means there is no mapping for this request. May be I do not know something, but I think this code should work, but not. Browser does not see the proper mapping. What is going wrong? Also I have tried set `@ComponentScan` annotation, but, as I have read, correct me please, there is no so need in this case. Anyway, `ComponentScan` annotation dose not solve my problem. Correct my if I wrong) Below I will paste the examples of my code.

This is my Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/catalog")
public class MovieCatalogResource {

    @GetMapping("/{userID}")
    public List<CatalogItem> getCatalog(@PathVariable("userID") String userId) {
        return Collections.singletonList(
                new CatalogItem("", "", 10)
        );
    }
}
```

And this is the main (There is nothing special here, only starting the Spring-Boot application, but I guess it may be helpful for you)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MovieCatalogServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MovieCatalogServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: And the interesting part is left out... The package structure.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134333/this-application-has-no-explicit-mapping-for-error

Comment: Can you share structure and component scan annotation which you defined?

Comment: of course, it is my fault. I am completely forgot about springbootapplication default scan components only by native directory. You have ny gratitude!