# Response code 403 while fetching request using React

Tags: reactjs, curl, fetch, http-status-code-403

I have a react client on port 8070
I'm getting requests from port 8090

Request: curl -X GET "http://localhost:8090/get/directory" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "path: /"

This is how i'm fetching this request:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const requestOptions = {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Path": "/",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
    };
    fetch(
      "http://localhost:8090/get/directory",
      requestOptions
    ).then((response) => console.log(response));
  }, []);
```

This is what i've got:

[image]

Maybe someone has any ideas why i'm getting 403 error? Maybe something wrong with how i'm fetching this request?

Comment: Try hitting this get url in browser and check are you getting the response http://localhost:8090/get/directory

Comment: Is cors enabled on your back end

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS this is what i've got "Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Dec 07 11:32:23 GMT 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400)."

Comment: Is the backend is written in java, check this one i don't have much context on java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134333/this-application-has-no-explicit-mapping-for-error

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS yeah in java. ok, thanks, i'll check