# I need aids setting up my heroku deployment - logs show no error, page shows 404

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, heroku, deployment

I have managed to deploy my app on heroku successfully. here is log

```
2021-02-24T20:36:45.711648+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-02-24 20:36:45.711  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5c2375a9, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@59cba5a, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@301eda63, org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter@60129b9a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@3f67593e, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@6f19ac19, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@768fc0f2, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@78d6692f, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@341814d3, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@20f5281c]
2021-02-24T20:36:45.823041+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-02-24 20:36:45.822  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-02-24T20:36:46.292036+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-02-24 20:36:46.291  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService 'taskScheduler'
2021-02-24T20:36:46.358202+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-02-24 20:36:46.357  INFO 4 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 47499 (http) with context path ''
2021-02-24T20:36:46.375800+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-02-24 20:36:46.375  INFO 4 --- [           main] org.marius.projekt.Main                  : Started Main in 5.904 seconds (JVM running for 7.982)
2021-02-24T20:36:46.528468+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-02-24T20:37:30.409312+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-02-24 20:37:30.409  INFO 4 --- [io-47499-exec-3] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-02-24T20:37:30.409435+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-02-24 20:37:30.409  INFO 4 --- [io-47499-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-02-24T20:37:30.419132+00:00 app[web.1]: 2021-02-24 20:37:30.418  INFO 4 --- [io-47499-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 9 ms
2021-02-24T20:37:30.641157+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=tvoje-pocasie.herokuapp.com request_id=06668414-6a22-4320-8ed5-3d7a17a26f1d fwd="188.167.228.254" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=266ms status=404 bytes=780 protocol=https
2021-02-24T20:38:49.703274+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=tvoje-pocasie.herokuapp.com request_id=bf50a347-205c-4877-9d45-07ab0bcda6bd fwd="188.167.228.254" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=17ms status=404 bytes=780 protocol=https
2021-02-24T20:39:06.634908+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/forecast" host=tvoje-pocasie.herokuapp.com request_id=e211f62c-a8c1-4166-8d3e-f09778bea073 fwd="188.167.228.254" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=13ms status=404 bytes=780 protocol=https
```

My heroku local is running fine.
I am using gradle with groovy on backend side and react on frontend
my application.properties:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=${MONGO_URI}
spring.data.mongodb.host=${HOST}
#spring.data.mongodb.host=tvoje-pocasie.herokuapp.com
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
#spring.data.mongodb.port=5837
spring.data.mongodb.database=weatherManager
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=256MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=256MB
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
```

where HOST is https://tvoje-pocasie.herokuapp.com/

I have also tried

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=${MONGO_URI}
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
#spring.data.mongodb.host=tvoje-pocasie.herokuapp.com
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
#spring.data.mongodb.port=5837
spring.data.mongodb.database=weatherManager
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=256MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=256MB
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true
```

I can do curl calls.
I know not what else to try. logs s

Comment: It seems as though your application is deployed properly it's just getting an error while processing the request.  Note how the page displayed on the link above says your application has nothing mapped for the /error path.  You need to debug your code and find out why it's getting an error and trying to show an error page.

Comment: Also this maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134333/this-application-has-no-explicit-mapping-for-error