# Error in Spring boot Whitelabel Error Page This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback

Tags: java, validation, exception

In browser getting below error rather than JSON Error message but it is working in Postman.I need print the JSON Error message in Browser . Anyone can help here how to display the error message in JSON format in Browser

Browser :
**Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Wed Nov 29 17:10:21 UTC 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
Resource Not Found**

Postman :

```
{
    "timestamp": "2023-11-29T18:21:30.864+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "Resource Not Found",
    "path": "/getDetails"
}

Java code :

Exception 
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ValidationExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public void constraintViolationException(HttpServletResponse response,ConstraintViolationException e) throws IOException {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<?>> violations = e.getConstraintViolations();
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (ConstraintViolation<?> violation : violations ) {
            strBuilder.append(violation.getMessage() + '\n');
        }
         ResponseEntity.status(BAD_REQUEST);
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value());
    }
    @ExceptionHandler(ValidationException.class)
    public void dateViolationException(HttpServletResponse response, ValidationException e) throws IOException {
       if(e.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("Resource Not Found")){
           ResponseEntity.status(NOT_FOUND);
           response.sendError(NOT_FOUND.value(), e.getMessage());
        }else{
           if(e.getMessage().equalsIgnoreCase("User Not Found in the system")){
               ResponseEntity.status(UNAUTHORIZED);
               response.sendError(UNAUTHORIZED.value(), e.getMessage());
       }
        else{
            ResponseEntity.status(BAD_REQUEST);
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(), e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}}

Controller :

@RequestMapping(value = "/getDetails", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @Validated
    public Object getSearchCriteria(@RequestParam(value = "Id") String Id,
                                            @RequestParam(value = "service", required = false) String service) throws ParseException, JsonProcessingException, javax.xml.bind.ValidationException {

        if (system != null && !system.isEmpty())
            documentMap.put("system", s);
        List<? extends Bson> pipelines = getAggregate(queryLimit, projectFields, documentMap);
       
        List listDetails = collectionDB.aggregate(pipelines).into(Aggregate);
        if (listDetails.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ValidationException(RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND);
        }
        return getPrettyDocument(listDetails);
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This application has no explicit mapping for /error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31134333/this-application-has-no-explicit-mapping-for-error)

Comment: @Abra , Sorry getting back to you very late. I have already followed the reference link but it didn't work for me . Could you please suggest in case of any suggestions